# Unity collider going through other colliders at times?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, collision, rigid-bodies

I'm trying to create a Pong clone for practice. I setup my project in 2D.

The paddle has the following components:

- -Rigidbody2D (set to `kinematic`)
- -BoxCollider2D (is a `trigger`)

The ball has the following components:

- -Rigidbody2D (set to `kinematic`)
- -CircleCollider2D (is a `trigger`)

The paddle is controlled via dragging (user dragging finger on screen left/right). I used the `EasyTouch` plugin for this.

Then I move the ball with this script:

```
void Update () {
        transform.position += new Vector3(xSpeed * Time.deltaTime, ySpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

This is how I detect collisions and redirect the ball once it hits something (Horizontal objects are the top/bottom/paddle while Vertical objects are the left/right screen border):

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D c)
    {
        if(c.gameObject.tag.Equals("Horizontal"))
        {
            ySpeed *= -1;
        }
        else if(c.gameObject.tag.Equals("Vertical"))
        {
            xSpeed *= -1;
        }

    }
```

The problem is sometimes the ball goes through the paddle which can look glitchy to the end-user. I've searched about this online and I've tried to set the rigidbody's `Collision Detection` property to `Continuous` instead of `Discrete`. But the ball still goes through the paddle at certain times.

Anyone know how to solve this? What am I doing wrong with how I setup/coded my game?

Thanks

Comment: It is no problem in the physics engine because you are not using any physics. Add some debug logs for checking what is happening when your ball glitches

Comment: its funny how people assume its more likely that its unitys fault rather then theirs. why dont you search a pong tutorial for unity, theres plenty and it takes only an hour or two, but you save yourself from a lot of frustration if you know how things work before you try your own ideas. please dont take it as offensive, even if i was a bit sarcastic in the beginning :)

Comment: Thanks both for the advice. Yeah I'll go ahead with the tutorials and brush up. It's been a long while since I touched game dev and Unity. I feel like a newbie again :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a very simple concept error.
OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D) is to get if the collider has entered other collider. In other words you can go through the object.

you need to use this function instead:

```
OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll)
```

I suggest you to watch this Unity tutorial because it explains all this really good: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/physics/colliders

Additional info : http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.html

Thanks.

Comment: When I saw your post, I realized that it should be OnCollisionEnter instead of OnTriggerEnter based on my needs. Rookie mistake on my end. I'll go ahead with the tutorials you shared! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As the code shows, the transform is controlled by yourself while the continuous detection requires control of physics engine, so try to control the gameObject with physics engine instead give it a position modified by your own code.

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried leaving the movement behavior to the physics engine and it doesn't go through colliders anymore which is good. However, the movement that is produced is not what I want for a Pong game. I'll go ahead and watch some tutorials regarding this